# A characterisation of nowhere dense sets

Tags: general-topology

Can you give me a hint, why the following characterisation of a nowhere dense set $A$ (where my definition of n.d. is $ \textrm{Int(cl}(A))=\emptyset$) should hold:

For all nonempty open set $U$ there exists an open set $V$, such that $V \subseteq U$ and $A\cap V = \emptyset$ (I found this characterisation on the French Wikipedia [article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_nulle_part_dense) for n.d. sets).

Comment: I think you meant $A \cap V = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks.

Comment: temo: the condition is still not what I meant, it's $A$ not $U$

Comment: From just the term "Nowhere dense", the latter classification sounds more like it should be the "real" one. But that's just me rambling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(a) $\operatorname{Int}\overline A=\emptyset$ $\Leftrightarrow$ 
(b) There is no non-empty open set $U\subseteq\overline A$. $\Leftrightarrow$ 
(c) If $U$ is a non-empty open set then $U\setminus\overline A\ne\emptyset$. $\Leftrightarrow$ 
(d) If $U$ is a non-empty open set then there exists a non-empty open open set $V$ such that $V\subseteq U\setminus\overline A$. $\Leftrightarrow$ 
(e) If $U$ is a non-empty open set then there exists a non-empty open open set $V$ such that $V\subseteq U\setminus A$.

Equivalence of the last two conditions follows from $\operatorname{Int} (U\setminus A)=U\setminus\overline{A}$.

- The inclusion $\operatorname{Int} (U\setminus A)\supseteq U\setminus\overline{A}$ is clear, since $U\setminus\overline{A}$ is an open set and $U\setminus\overline{A}\subseteq U\setminus A$.
- On the other hand, if $V\subseteq U\setminus A$ is an open set, then $V\cap A=\emptyset$. This implies $V\cap\overline A=\emptyset$. We have shown that
  $V\subseteq U\setminus \overline A$ holds for every open subset $V$ of $U\setminus A$. This means that 
  $\operatorname{Int} (U\setminus A)\subseteq U\setminus\overline{A}$.

---

You can also find similar proof in the book Elements of Metric Spaces by M.N. Mukherjee [p.89](http://books.google.com/books?id=LA8dS7-JkCsC&pg=PA89).
(I found this book simply by typing ["let A be nowhere dense"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22let+a+be+nowhere+dense%22) into google, I do not know how good this book is. However, proof of this result seems fine.)